# jQuery: FadeToggle + div A calling div B

Tags: jquery

Overview: upon the mouse hovering over div A, then div B fades in. Then you can move your move into div B.

I'm satisfied with all of the characteristics in my demo, but there are some problems that I cannot overcome. I think I'm approaching it from the wrong angle.

**Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/t1c76m6g/**

---

Issues I'm facing:

- Sometimes the submenu gets double toggled. *(To reproduce: hover over Button1, move the mouse into Submenu1, move the mouse back into Button1, and then exit through the top of Button1.)* **[GIF screen capture](http://i.imgur.com/HcgnpY9.gif)**
- If you move the mouse from a button to its submenu too fast, then the submenu fadeIn is interrupted and it just instantly pops on instead. **[GIF screen capture](http://i.imgur.com/fuoW6s2.gif)**
- Can this same effect (div A calling div B) be achieved with CSS3 instead?

---

Jquery

```
$( "#button1" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#submenu1" ).stop().fadeToggle(1000, function() {
  });
});

$( "#button2" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#submenu2" ).stop().fadeToggle(1000, function() {
  });
});

$( "#button3" ).hover(function() {
  $( "#submenu3" ).stop().fadeToggle(1000, function() {
  });
});


$( ".chain" ).mouseenter(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeIn(0);  
});

$( ".chain" ).mouseout(function() {
    $(this).stop().fadeOut(1000);  
});
```

---

HTML

```
<div id="button_container">
<div id="button1">Button 1</div>
<div id="button2">Button 2</div>
<div id="button3">Button 3</div>

<div id="submenu1" class="chain">Submenu 1</div>
<div id="submenu2" class="chain">Submenu 2</div>
<div id="submenu3" class="chain">Submenu 3</div>
</div>
```

---

CSS

```
#button_container {
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:50px;
}

#button1,#button2,#button3 {
display:inline-block;
background-color:LightBlue;
font-size:30px;
cursor:pointer;
}

.chain {
display:none;
}

#submenu1 {
background:red;
width:200px;
height:100px;
position:fixed;
}
#submenu2 {
background:blue;
width:300px;
height:200px;
position:fixed;
}
#submenu3 {
background:orange;
width:400px;
height:300px;
position:fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there seems to be a lot of animations breaks in your code as far as I can tell. I don't think in this case you should use .hover but rather .mouseenter and .mouseleave.

Check this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button1").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#submenu1").stop().fadeIn();
         }).mouseleave(function() {
      $( "#submenu1" ).stop().fadeOut(300);
    });   

    $("#button2").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#submenu2").stop().fadeIn();
         }).mouseleave(function() {
        $( "#submenu2" ).stop().fadeOut(300);
    }); 

     $("#button3").mouseenter(function() {
        $("#submenu3").stop().fadeIn();
         }).mouseleave(function() {
      $( "#submenu3" ).stop().fadeOut(300);
    });    

    $("#submenu1, #submenu2, #submenu3").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeIn(0);  
    });

    $( "#submenu1, #submenu2, #submenu3" ).mouseout(function() {
        $(this).stop().fadeOut(300);  
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t1c76m6g/1/

As for your why does it instantly fades in when you hover of sub div, well it's simple. YOu use .stop() and that cancels all other animations that are affecting that selector. Having it coupled with .fadein(0), you get the picture.

Affecting other divs with css is not possible; You can maybe work around something with :before.

Comment: One more question. I just realized that upon adding div's into the #submenu container, then those children are not inheriting the mouseenter and it fades out. I've tried adding .children() and .find() but can't figure it out. Any ideas? Here is an updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/t1c76m6g/2/

Comment: Yeah. You'll just need to add this piece of code. Check: http://jsfiddle.net/t1c76m6g/5/